# How to query specific named graph in Jena TDB?

Tags: sparql, jena, tdb, named-graphs

I am trying the tutorials of Jena [here](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_datasets.html). I encounter similar problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831109/querying-named-rdf-graphs-in-tdb-using-tdbquery), but it does not solve my problem. I've already loaded my data into tdb and when I query with `SELECT DISTINCT ?g {GRAPH ?g {}}`, the results are as follows:

```
-----------------
| g             |
=================
| <ds-ng-1.ttl> |
| <ds-ng-2.ttl> |
-----------------
```

but when i try to query with following query in tdb I've got no results.

```
PREFIX  dc:     <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX  :       <.>

SELECT ?title
{ 
  GRAPH :ds-ng-2.ttl
      { ?b dc:title ?title }
}
```

According to the similar question I've mentioned above, @RobV mentioned

> If you get an absolute URI back then you can specify that directly in your original query, if you do not then there is no way to query for it from the command line.

I'd like to ask is it real? If so, how can I use API to execute this query? My codes are as follows:

```java
    String directory = "path_to\\datasets\\data_graph\\tdbtest";
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory);  
    Model tdb = dataset.getDefaultModel();
    String queryString = "PREFIX  dc:<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> \nPREFIX  :  <.> \nSELECT ?title { GRAPH :ds-ng-2.ttl { ?b dc:title ?title }}";
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    try(QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, tdb)){
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
    }
```

But I still get now results. I'm not sure how I can select multiple models no matter it's a default or named model.

Comment: You have to use the same `BASE` in the SPARQL query as you had when loading the data into the graph. Or how did you load the data?

Comment: I use tdbloader to load the data with `tdbloader --loc=path\to\tdb -graph=ds-ng-1.ttl ds-ng-1.ttl` and `tdbloader --loc=path\to\tdb -graph=ds-ng-2.ttl ds-ng-2.ttl` to load the two named graphs, I'm not sure if i am correct about loading named graphs. I try to use the local file location as `base` but sparql gives me a syntax error. I do not know whether I can use a local directory as base.

Comment: What do you write for `BASE` in the query and which syntax error? And why don't you use a full URI as graph when loading?

Comment: I use `BASE <C:\Users\weiling\Documents\datasets\data_graph>`. The error is `Encountered " <PNAME_NS> "C: "" at line 3, column 6.
Was expecting:    <IRIref> ...`. When you talking about using a full URI, do you mean to use `tdbloader --loc=path\to\tdb -graph=ds-ng-1.ttl C:\Users\weiling\Documents\datasets\data_graph\ds-ng-1.ttl`??

Comment: That is not a valid URI! A URI starts with a protocol.

Comment: No I mean the graph declaration. `-graph` denotes the IRI of the graph in which you want to load the data. See `tdbloader --help`

Comment: I'm not sure if the `<.>` namespace is a good idea, that might not be the same. Can you try with `GRAPH  <ds-ng-1.ttl>` instead?

Comment: @AdrianGschwend yes, i tried, still no results.

Comment: To see if you have managed to load the named graphs at all do: SELECT * WHERE {GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o  }} This will rule out weird naming of the graphs causing errors and display the graph names. If you still can't see any data query the default graph to see if it ended up there. If you can't figure out the problem I would consider converting the ttl-files into trig prior to loading.